# AngularJS child directive not called when parent directive using templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a little tired of data grid initialization code, so I am trying something new with AngularJS. I would like to specify my data grid inline like so:

```
<grid src="http://my/web/service" page-size="10">
    <column name="one" label="My First Column" />
    <column name="two" label="My Second Column" />
    <column name="three" label="My Last Column">
        <value id="true" label="Yay" />
        <value id="false" label="Nay" />
    <column>
</grid>
```

Basically, I am trying to configure the grid with easy xml (non-js) semantics instead of clumsy initializers. For this, I have created three directives, the outer most directive also has a template, that will display the grid.

**Problem is:** When you configure a template for the outer element, the inner elements aren't linked (which is required for configuration of the grid). I do not want to transclude the inner elements either.

**Question is:** How can I access the *original* contents of the grid element? Both the contents of the template element/element instance are the contents of the template.

You can inspect my code at http://plnkr.co/edit/rb9yyogQEmoLXFhWpl8F

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `template` or `templateUrl` properties of directive definition object since it overwrite whatever content the element has.

You'll need to add the template on your own.

```
.directive("grid", function(){
   return {
      //...
      link: function(scope, element){
         // this assumes that your child directives have registered themselves and 
         // are no longer needed
         element.empty();
         var templateUrl = "grid.html";
         element.append("<div ng-include='\"" + templateUrl + "\"'></div>");
         $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
   }
})
```